# How to make a PHP file unavailable to users?

Tags: php, security, files

I have a file `queue.php` which I have set up as a cron job. I don't want users to be able to access it. How can I do this?

Comment: are you running the cron job via HTTP or from shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight file permissions should do the trick. Just make the file readable by the user that cron runs as and not by anyone else.

`chmod [restricted-user]:[restricted-group] 640` should do it.

Comment: How can I do this via FTP access?

Comment: @JonathanLingle Depends on the server and client, but I would say you've got a good chance of being able to do it. Log in with ftp and type `help` to see what response you get. `chmod` over ftp is common.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Here's [an image](http://puu.sh/pg3m) showing what I'm doing. Unfortunately, the user is still able to run `queue.php`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JonathanLingle What user is the web server running as?

Comment: What I suspect is that you are on a shared hosting account and the web server is running as your user account. If that's the case, you only have access to one user account and group, so you'll probably need to use some kind of .htaccess restriction to keep people from viewing it on any device except localhost.

Comment: @JonathanLingle Awesome! Thanks for updating us. =)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on external dependencies I usually do this by restricting the permissions on the file on the Linux side and putting the file itself outside of the public web root to guarantee it cannot be accessed by anyone except the server.

If for some reason the file cannot exist outside the web root (perhaps due to an openbasedir restriction or some kind of pathing issue) the straight unix permissions as suggested by Wesley David would do the trick.

You could also use .htaccess or even php itself to restrict how the script can be executed.

Comment: +1 for being outside web root.